# Problems in merging two associative arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two arrays in PHP.I am facing difficulty in merging this two arrays

```
$scheduleArray0=Array ([04/04/2016] => 
                    Array ( [TypeName_1] => Weekly
                          [TypeID_1] => 3)
                   [04/05/2016] =>
                    Array ( [TypeName_1] => Weekly 
                          [TypeID_1] => 3  ) 
                   )


 $scheduleArray1 = Array ( [04/04/2016] => 
                   Array ( [TypeName_2] => Biweekly 
                           [TypeID_2] => 7 ) 
                     [04/05/2016] =>
                  Array ( [TypeName_2] => Biweekly 
                          [TypeID_2] => 7 ) ) .
```

I need it to merge like this.ie My **required output**

```
$final =    Array ( [04/04/2016] => 
                  Array ( [TypeName_1] => Weekly [TypeID_1] => 3 
                          [TypeName_2] => Biweekly [TypeID_2] => 7 )
               [04/05/2016] => 
                  Array ( [TypeName_1] => Weekly [TypeID_1] => 3
                          [TypeName_2] => Biweekly [TypeID_2] => 7 ) )
```

For merging I have used the following code

```
$final = merge_common_keys($scheduleArray0,$scheduleArray1);
```

Its giving me the following multidimensional array.**This is what I get**

```
Array ([04/04/2016] => 
        Array ( [0] => Array ( [TypeName_1] => Weekly [TypeID_1] => 3 )
                [1] => Array ( [TypeName_2] => Biweekly [TypeID_2] => 7  )) 
       [04/05/2016] => 
        Array ( [0] => Array ( [TypeName_1] => Weekly [TypeID_1] => 3  ) 
                [1] => Array ( [TypeName_2] => Biweekly [TypeID_2] => 7 ) )
```

The user defined function-merge_common_keys

```
function merge_common_keys(){
    $arr = func_get_args();
    $num = func_num_args();

    $keys = array();
    $i = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<$num; ++$i){
        $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($arr[$i]));
    }
    $keys = array_unique($keys);

    $merged = array();

    foreach ($keys as $key){
        $merged[$key] = array();
        for($i=0; $i<$num; ++$i){
            $merged[$key][] = isset($arr[$i][$key]) ? $arr[$i][$key] : null;
        }
    }
    return $merged;
```

}

**EDIT** -When I merged two arrays with `array_merge()`,I am not getting the `$schedule_array0` values in the merged array

Comment: Can you please provide the function `merge_common_keys`?

Comment: @tommy I have added the merge_common_keys() defenition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function merge_common_keys() {
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    $result = [];

    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if ( ! array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
                $result[$key] = [];
            }

            $result[$key] = array_merge($result[$key], $value);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The result is:

[image]